# Only allow keys defined from another JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to make a structure using JSON Schemas, that allow me to define a key-value object containing enum values (`options.json`), but also a query schema that is used to validate a certain query (`query.json`). To prevent code duplication, I'm looking for a way to only allow keys in my query schema to be keys that are defined in my other schema. The most annoying part is, that when I'm querying, I might want both "value1" and "value2" matches. So what I want to achieve, is that my query only has keys defined as properties in `options.json`, but it should accept either `value1` as value or `["value1", "value2"]` as value.

```
// options.json
{
  "id": "options.json",
  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "option1": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
      ]
    },
    "option2": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "value4",
        "value5",
        "value6"
      ]
    }
  },

  "required": []
}
```

Now for some sample data:

```
// should be marked as valid
{
  "option1": "value1"
}

// this as well
{
  "option1": ["value1", "value2"]
}

// combination of the two also valid
{
  "option1": "value1",
  "option2": ["value5", "value6"]
}

// but this shouldn't
{
  "option3": "doesn't exist"
}
```

How can I achieve such a structure?

The closest I can get to what I want would be something like this, but it would still mean I manually have to define each key that's specified in options:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "option1": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "options.json#/properties/option1"
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "options.json#/properties/option1",
            "uniqueItems": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like what you're asking for could be solved by using `additionalProperties: false` in options, and `$ref: options.json` in query.json, but I'm not sure I fully understand what you want. Have you looked at `$ref`?

Comment: I added an example of what I already think would work, but would require manual maintaining, or a script that preprocesses the `options.json` file into what I need.

Comment: I think I understand. Yes I think you would have to maintain this yourself. HOWEVER, there's no reason you can't generate the JSON Schema for `query`!

Comment: As of now, indeed, I can just generate it, but in the future I might have more complex queries where some query values could have additional structures (like supporting ranges, etc).

Comment: It's kind of a hack right now huh? We are looking into supporting what you really need. Keep an eye on https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%24data

Comment: Wouldn't the use of a hyper schema resolve my issues? Use something the like of `"$ref": "options.json#/properties/{3#}"`? In case of the first object in the `anyOf` array, this would resolve to `option1` if I'm correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what hyperschema has to do with this, nor to which part you see which leads you to that as a solution. I'm not overly familiar with HS though. Feel free to join the JSON Schema slack if you would like to further discuss this =]